# How to draw smooth curve according to given height

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, curve

I want to drive a smooth curve that curve's 1/3 is outward 2/3 is inward.This is what I want to achieve.

[image]

So far , I tried this with adding 1 curve like :

```
  var height: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 14
  let centerWidth = self.frame.width / 2 
  let screenView = UIScreen.main.bounds
  let width = (screenView.width - (2*screenView.width/40)) / 10

     path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)) // start top left
     path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth - width * 2.5), y: 0)) // the beginning of the trough
           // first curve down
     path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: centerWidth   , y: height),
                     controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth - width * 1.33), y: 0), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: centerWidth - width * 1.33  , y: height))
```

But when I try this outward and inward curve's have same height. So I changed it and tried adding 2 curve like :

```
     path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)) // start top left
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth - width * 2.5), y: 0)) // the beginning of the trough
        // first curve down
    path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: centerWidth - width * 1.33 , y: height/3),
                  controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth - width * 1.33), y: 0), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: centerWidth - width * 1.33 , y: height/3))

    path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: centerWidth, y: height),
                                    controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: centerWidth - width * 1.33 , y: height/3), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: centerWidth - width , y: height  ))
```

It similar to what I want but junction point doesnt look the curve is a single piece
[image]

I have tried so many things but cant draw what I want exacly.So How can I draw a curve that endpoint height's 1/3 gonna be outward and 2/3 inward that looks like a one piece.

I'm open to all kinds of ideas to draw.Regards

> NOTE

I'm trying to customize `tabbar`'s center button which height value  is `UIScreen.main.bounds.height` and width is `

```
let screenView = UIScreen.main.bounds
let width = (screenView.width - (2*screenView.width/40))`
```

Comment: By the way, I would advise against ever using `UIScreen.main.bounds` in one’s drawing code. It makes it very brittle, and will fail if it’s ever used in a split-screen multitasking environment, like an iPad. Always just reference the view’s `bounds`, not the screen dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

As I look at your designer’s rendering, if you are breaking this into two separate Bézier curves, the key observation is that the top ⅓ curve is symmetrical (with respect to itself) as is the bottom ⅔ curve. And for symmetrical Bézier curves, a quad Bézier is easier to deal with.

And to make the inflection point seamless, you’ll want to ensure that two control points (one for the quad Bézier above the inflection point, the other for the quad Bézier below the inflection point) are collinear with the inflection point itself. E.g.:

[image]

It takes a little trigonometry to figure out the placement of these control points, e.g.

```
let center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.midX, y: 200)
let radius: CGFloat = 140
let curveOffsetBottom: CGFloat = 30
let curveOffsetInflection: CGFloat = 50

greenCircularShapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * .pi, clockwise: true).cgPath

let h = radius + curveOffsetBottom + 50

let curveBottom = CGPoint(x: center.x,
                          y: center.y + radius + curveOffsetBottom)

let y0 = radius + curveOffsetBottom - h * 2 / 3
let t0 = asin(y0 / (radius + curveOffsetInflection))
let x0 = y0 / tan(t0)

let inflectionPoint = CGPoint(x: center.x - x0, y: center.y + y0)

let t1 = atan((curveBottom.x - inflectionPoint.x) / (curveBottom.y - inflectionPoint.y))

let t2 = 2 * (.pi / 2 - t1)

let x2 = (curveBottom.y - inflectionPoint.y) / tan(t2)
let x1 = x2 / 2

let cp1 = CGPoint(x: inflectionPoint.x - x1, y: curveBottom.y - h)
let cp2 = CGPoint(x: inflectionPoint.x + x2, y: curveBottom.y)

let curveTop = CGPoint(x: cp1.x - cp1.distance(to: inflectionPoint), y: curveBottom.y - h)

let path = UIBezierPath()
path.move(to: curveTop)
path.addQuadCurve(to: inflectionPoint, controlPoint: cp1)
path.addQuadCurve(to: curveBottom, controlPoint: cp2)

path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: view.bounds.maxX, y: path.currentPoint.y))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: view.bounds.maxX, y: view.bounds.maxY))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: view.bounds.minX, y: view.bounds.maxY))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: view.bounds.minX, y: curveTop.y))
path.close()

blackCurveShapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
```

Where

```
extension CGPoint {
    func distance(to point: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
        hypot(point.x - x, point.y - y)
    }
}
```

Comment: I did try but getting error `Value of type 'CGPoint' has no member 'distance'` . What is the `cp1.distance` function?

Comment: @OmerTekbiyik - Sorry, it’s a little extension I use on `CGPoint` that just calls `hypot` to calculate the distance between two points. Updated answer to include that. Above I use it to ensure that the starting point is equidistant from the control point as the inflection point is.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I'm trying to customize tabbar which center button need to look what u draw but when I try to ur code some of x points are out of screen so couldn't draw it

Comment: @OmerTekbiyik That’s fine. You can move the position of the circular shape layer and change the various constants as needed. This should render appropriately regardless of size and position. Besides, don’t get lost in all of that is implementation detail. The main point is that achieve the designer’s effect with two quad Bézier whose control points are equidistant from the endpoints and collinear with the inflection point.

Comment: Thanks for your advice I'm gonna try @Rob